# prime numbers - number theory examples

Tags: number-theory

True of False? if True Please proof it else take a counterexample!
Note that m>1,
[image]

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something, because doesn't $m = n_1 = 1, p_1 = p = 2$ give a trivial counterexample?

Comment: Maybe one needs to assume $m>1$ (and that "disjoint" prime numbers means distinct prime numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equation is multiplied by $p_1 \cdots p_m$ the left side becomes a positive integer and the right side is $(p_1 \cdots p_m)/p$, from which since all are primes it follows that $p$ is one of the $p_k$ for some $k$. Then subtraction of $1/p$ from each side of your equation gives a positive number equal to $0$, since each numerator is at least $1$ and there are at least two terms on the left.